# Swift compilation time with nil coalescing operator

Tags: swift, compilation

After reading of the [article](https://habrahabr.ru/post/283106/) about swift compiling time. I am interested in why usage of more than 2 sequence coalescing operator increase compilation time significantly.

Example:
 Compilation time 3.65 sec.

```
 func fn() -> Int {    
        let a: Int? = nil
        let b: Int? = nil
        let c: Int? = nil

        return 999 + (a ?? 0) + (b ?? 0) + (c ?? 0)
 }
```

Compilation time 0.09 sec.

```
func fn() -> Int {

    let a: Int? = nil
    let b: Int? = nil
    let c: Int? = nil

    var res: Int = 999

    if let a = a {
        res += a
    }

    if let b = b {
        res += b
    }

    if let c = c {
        res += c
    }

    return res
}
```

Comment: Is this still valid in swift 4 or swift 5?  I understand the principles behind the cause (type inference) but it seems like something that could have been improved by now.

Comment: @rmooney I added the first function into one of my existing files, and the compiler just straight-up errored out, saying that it was unable to resolve the expression in a reasonable time. I don't think it's resolved yet.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm almost certain that this has to do with type inference. When interpreting all of those `+` and `??` operators the compiler is doing a lot of work behind the scenes to infer the types of those arguments. There are around thirty overloads for the `+` operator alone and when you chain several of them together you are making the compiler's job much more complicated than you might think.