# Why does nil-coalescing compile faster with string interpolation than when used in expressions?

Tags: swift

In my project I have a script to generate warnings when a func takes longer than 500ms to compile.

Given the following code:

```
struct User {
    var firstName: String?
    var lastName: String?
}

let user = User(firstName: "John", lastName: nil)

let expression = (user.firstName ?? "") + " " + (user.lastName ?? "")
let interpolated = "\(user.firstName ?? "") \(user.lastName ?? "")"
```

I have found that `expression` takes ~700ms to compile, whereas `interpolated` takes less that 500ms.

I came across this post (https://stackoverflow.com/a/37102686/4442390) that mentions type inference takes the majority of the time. Given that, my assumption is that `expression` is performing type inference, whereas `interpolated` is not (does it just cast as string?) so compiles faster.

Is my assumption true?

Comment: there is an Apple Swift Users Forum for users https://forums.swift.org/c/swift-users . Maybe there you get more details

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely the problem is the `+` operator. The operator is heavily overloaded (e.g. for numbers) therefore there are multiple possible types. My guess is that `??` does not make much difference there, only to make the expression more complicated and therefore harder to evaluate.

Also note that there are multiple bugs reported for this, for example [SR-2877](https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-2877) or [SR-1107](https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-1107) (for integers).

Historically, there were also bugs related to `??` but I think many of them have been already fixed.

Comment: Looks like you're right. I tested it with a new infix operator and it didn't have the same compile time issues. https://gist.github.com/chris-paterson/6a1ec86107d00b36b5aa908b8b9b2fc9

Comment: @ChristopherPaterson Actually, looking at your linked question, the answer already answers your question :)